# If I have multiple YouTube brand channels, can other users see they are related?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel

If I have multiple brand channels under a single YouTube login, can the public see that they are related, and can users see that I am the owner of one/all?

I wish to keep different client concerns separate, they are diverse and often contradictory brands/tones/messages and they would not be happy being associated with one another. Would their common "owner" (me) be visible to anyone?

Answer (score -1):

I honestly dont think they can, cuz i have tried to see a channels other channels or their accounts.  My fear is though, websites change how they do things all the time.